# When do we need #ifdef before #undef?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, macros, undef

In many of the C and C++ files I have seen macros like this:

```
#ifdef X
#undef X  // no statements in between
#endif
```

I feel that, it's adequate to simply write:

```
#undef X
```

If the macro `X` wasn't defined, then the `#undef` should have no effect.

Is it *ok* to put standalone `#undef`, if I want to only *undefine* a macro ? Does that make the coding practice bad in anyway ?

Comment: I agree; I just did a quick search and this behaviour seems to be consistent across the major compilers. Perhaps some historically did not allow you to undef an undefined macro? Not sure. I'd say that it's probably safe.

Comment: Seems to me that it is fine all by itself

Comment: I think I remember atleast MSVC erroring out on me with that.

Comment: @Xeo, maybe in the past. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4w8783(v=vs.80).aspx) reckons that it's OK as of VS2005.

Comment: @anthony: The docs actually say it's valid as far back as VS 2003. It's probably VC 6 he's thinking of, notorious for its lack of standards compliance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See ISO C99 6.10.3.5 paragraph 2.

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # undef identifier new-line
> ```
>
> causes the specified identifier no longer to be defined as a macro name. It is ignored if
>   the specified identifier is not currently defined as a macro name.

Even [Visual C++ 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa273931) (which was notorious for bad standards compliance) allows this:

> You can also apply the `#undef` directive to an identifier that has no previous definition. This ensures that the identifier is undefined. Macro replacement is not performed within `#undef` statements.

Comment: I can confirm that this is *exactly* the same for [ISO C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) as well.

Answer (score 12):

I'm sure it's an artifact of history. [As mentioned in jdigital's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090611/12711), the 2nd edition of K&R says

> It is not erroneous to apply #undef to an unknown identifier.

However, that sentence is not in the 1978 edition. I'm pretty sure pre-standard compilers would often throw an error if you tried to `#undef` an undefined macro.

Also, the [ANSI C Rationale says](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c8.html#3-8-3-5):

> It is explicitly permitted to #undef a macro that has no current definition.

I'd imagine that if it was already universal practice, there would be no need to call it out in the rationale.

All that said, it's not necessary in modern code, but it doesn't really hurt either.

Comment: I have no evidence but I'd wager that the C compilers of that era (first edition) would not throw an error.  It wouldn't fit with the Unix philosophy.

Comment: How's this for obsessive: I managed to Google-up an old DeSmet-C compiler for MS-DOS (ver 2.4 from 1984!), and it throws an error when I `#undef FOO` -- `3 # $$ undef FOO` / `error:not defined`

Comment: You win!  (MS-DOS people clearly didn't get the Unix philosophy.)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: please post your comment as an answer. I'd like to give you some rep for this.

Answer (score 9):

Kernighan and Ritchie (2nd edition) agree with you.

EDIT: quote from the source (section A12.3):

> A control line of the form
>
> `# undef` *identifier*
>
> causes the identifier's preprocessor definition to be forgotten.  If is not erroneous to apply `#undef` to an unknown identifier.

Comment: Can you quote from the source?

Comment: @anthony-arnold: quoted from source as requested.